# how to build a card with list in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

i'm a beginner in flutter and i have a problem .
i want to call  data from firebase.
[][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sA39.png

the goal is that every mail will be in a card but all mails appears in one biig card.
here is my code

```
'import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

 class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
   HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

 class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
   final Stream<QuerySnapshot> collectionReference =
       FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('students').snapshots();
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(),
         body: Container(
           child: StreamBuilder(
               stream: collectionReference,
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                 AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                  child: Card(
                      child: ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data!.docs
                        .map((e) => Column(
                              children: [
                                ListTile(title: Text(e['email'])),
                              ],
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                  )));
            }
            return Container();
          }),
    ));
  }
 }
```

Thank you for your help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code creates a `Card` containing a `ListView` with `ListTiles`, that's why you have one card containing all data.

If you want `Card` widgets in a `ListView`, each `Card` containing a `ListTitle` with email, try the following code from your `StreamBuilder`:

```
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
  child: ListView(
    children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((e) {
      return Card(
          child: Column(children: [
        ListTile(title: Text(e["name"]))
      ]));
    }).toList(),
  ),
);
```

But you don't really need `Column`, only if you will add more data there. If you need only email, it is simpler:

```
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
  child: ListView(
    children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((e) {
      return Card(
          child: ListTile(title: Text(e["name"])));
    }).toList(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: thanks bro it s very useful

Comment: You are welcome. If it helps consider marking my answer as accepted, thank you.